# Calling WCF service async from webservice - Image uploaded service

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, web-services

I am having a problem implementing an Async call to WCF for uploading images and processing from a webservice.

**ImageWCFService.svc.cs**

```
 public IAsyncResult BeginSaveImage(int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        // Create a task to do the work
        var task = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(this.SaveImage, state);

        return task.ContinueWith(res => callback(task));
    }


 public int EndSaveImage(IAsyncResult result)
  {
    return ((Task<int>)result).Result;
  }

public  int SaveImage(object state)
        {
             // the object state is a file stream
             // processes the image and uploaded it to CDN (Long process)
}
```

**IImageWCFService.cs**

```
 [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]    
 IAsyncResult BeginSaveImage(int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state);

 int EndSaveImage(IAsyncResult result);
```

**ImageWebService.asmx.cs**

```
 [ScriptMethod]
    protected void SaveImage(){

        HttpPostedFile file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];

        var proxy = new ImageServiceReference.ImageWCFServiceClient();

        object state = file.InputStream;

        var task = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(proxy.BeginSaveImage, proxy.EndSaveImage,10, state);
}
```

My goal is to enable async processing of images on the server to make image handling on the server more efficient.

The file will be uploaded via a webservice (.asmx) and from there I will run a tasnk to process the file stream that is passed to a 'state' object.

I am getting an error:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory<int>.FromAsync(System.IAsyncResult, System.Func<System.IAsyncResult,int>, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCreationOptions, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler)' has some invalid arguments
```

Although as a whoel I am not sure that I am doing everything the right way. But that's the best I was able to acheive reading this article on [MSDN.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2011/06/30/how-to-implement-a-wcf-asynchronous-service-operation-with-task-lt-t-gt.aspx).

I already created a service reference for the WCF service that generates a proxy client to call the WCF service async.

What I am missing in the code and what changes I need to make ot make it work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be that your code is missing a comma between 10 and state?

Comment: No, I just copy paste after playing a bit with the code. sorry for that I will fix that in the question

Comment: Please check the types of the arguments, as they do not fit the method signature. At least state is typed as an object but you would need a TaskScheduler instance for the overload mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Hi Martin, I am checking this out now..